# How to calculate the sum of an int array whose result exceeds Int32.Max value

Tags: c#

For example we have an int array:

```
var array = new int[]{ 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647};
```

What is the easiest way to calculate the sum of the array entries, **BUT in respect to the example provided above**?

`array.Sum()`

results in:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Because the result is not an int anymore..

Comment: The duplicate doesn't explain what to do if the sum overflows the Int32,MaxValue as requested here.

Comment: I put an code example in the question... so .....

Comment: `numSum = nums.Select( q => Convert.ToInt64(q)).Sum();`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the sum of the values in your array overflows the `Int32.MaxValue` you are forced to cast your elements to a long

```
var array = new int[]{ 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647};
var total = array.Sum(x => (long)x);
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

And you can see that the total variable is of type Int64

```
Console.WriteLine(total.GetType());
```

Comment: `myArray.Cast<long>().ToArray();` was what I was going to write, but I think yours is better.

Comment: Someone has downvoted, I would like to know if there is something wrong in the answer, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Steve's answer fits your question perfectly. However, if you need to store the sum of values that are longer than the typical datatypes you could use `BigInteger`.

```
var array = new [] { long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue };
var result = new BigInteger();
result = array.Aggregate(result, (current, i) => current + i);
```

This solution would also work for your provided array.

Comment: Well, someone here seems to disagree on providing help.

Comment: Decimal type can also be used to sum arrays of long[], as in `var total = array.Sum(x => (decimal)x);` which benchmarks about 5X faster than BigInteger. To go even faster `var total = array.AsParallel().Sum(x => (long)x); To go even faster still HPCsharp nuget package has .Sum() functions that use data parallel SSE instructions and use mutli-core parallelism as well.

Comment: @DragonSpit You are welcome to add your answer to the question. Keep in mind, my answer was meant to supply a way to achieve the desired result with numbers that the typical datatypes cannot handle. `Decimal` would fall into the category of typical as it has upper bounds.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Steve's solution to "How to sum a long[] array which exceeds Int64.MaxValue?", decimal type can be used to sum arrays of long[], as:

```
var array = new [] { long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue, long.MaxValue };
var result = array.Sum(x => (decimal)x);
```

decimal has a 96-bit mantissa, which is sufficient for a perfectly accurate result of an array with 2 Giga longs in it, which is the maximum size of an array in C# due to array index being limited to an Int32. Using the above decimal implementation is 5X faster than using BigInteger.

To go even faster:

```
result = array.AsParallel().Sum(x => (decimal)x);
```

this solution takes advantage of multi-core CPU for additional performance.

To go even faster, HPCsharp nuget package implements Sum() for int[], uint[], long[], ulong[] and all of the other signed and unsigned integers types, using data parallel SSE instructions, for faster performance on a single core, as well as parallel multi-core, while dealing with the sum exceeding MaxValue for each data type.