# Array.Sum() results in an overflow

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, int, overflow

I have an int array like this

```
int[] arr = {256741038,623958417,467905213,714532089,938071625};
```

and then I created an int64 var

```
Int64 sum = arr.Sum();
```

But this reslted in an overflow

> Run-time exception (line 19): Arithmetic operation resulted in an
>   overflow.

How can I solve this problem without using loop to sum it up ? (array type must be int)

Comment: `arr.Select(z => (long)z).Sum()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the sum of an int array whose result exceeds Int32.Max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515299/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-an-int-array-whose-result-exceeds-int32-max-value)

Comment: @vdthe The key thing to understand here is that `Sum` doesn't choose the return type based on what is needed to store the `Sum` (which, in this case would be a `long`). Instead, it chooses it based on the type of the enumerable being summed. You are summing `int` so, alas, it tries (unsuccessfully) to fit the sum into an `int`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is that while the individual values fit within an `int`, the sum of these numbers results is larger than an `int` can hold.

You therefore need to cast the values to `long` (or another datatype that takes numbers that big, but since you're using Int64...):

```
long sum = arr.Sum(v => (long)v);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to cast it to long so you don't overflow

```
var result = arr.Select(x => (long)x).Sum();
```

[int (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int)

> Range = `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

Some background, this is the source code for `Sum`

```
public static int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source) 
{
      if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
      int sum = 0;
      checked 
      {
          foreach (int v in source) 
             sum += v;
      }
      return sum;
}
```

Meaning, whether you like it or not, someone is using a for loop, additionaly the usage of `checked` is why it throws  :)

[checked (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked)

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find sum as shown below

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        int[] arr = {999999999, 999999999, 999999999,999999999, 999999999};
         long sum = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i += 1)
         {
           sum += arr[i];
         }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

[Datatype and Range Reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/data-types-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks but in my question I said that I don't want to use any kind of loop :)
@John's solution is fabulous

Answer (score 0):

When you call sum on array of integer, output type is an integer, and sum of entered numbers are more than integer maxvalue. as @TheGeneral said sum method check overflow and throw exception.

may be you expect the sum method return result as long, but its return type is an integer.

```
int a = 256741038;
int b = 623958417;
int c = 467905213;
int d = 714532089;
int e = 938071625;

long sumInt = a + b + c + d + e;
//-1293758914 //overflow happened withoud exception
long sumLong = (long)a + b + c + d + e;//clr now the result may be more than int.maxvalue
//3001208382
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way is as shown below

```
using System;
namespace Test
{
    public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int[] p = { 999999999, 999999999, 999999999, 999999999, 999999999 };
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long s = Sum;
        }
        public long Sum
        {
            get { long s = 0; Array.ForEach(p, delegate (int i) { s += i; }); return s; }
        }        
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks but in my question I said that I don't want to use any kind of loop :)

Comment: No issue I can understand and one another answer has been already given by another way so I can not repeat that but someone can get help from your question and different way...Thanks and welcome